# Naming the counter variables of consecutive for-loops

Tags: coding-style

Let's say you have a piece of code where you have a for-loop, followed by another for-loop and so on... now, which one is preferable

1. Give every counter variable the same name:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < someBound; i++) {
       doSomething();
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < anotherBound; i++) {
       doSomethingElse();
   }
   ```
2. Give them different names:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < someBound; i++) {
       doSomething();
   }

   for (int j = 0; j < anotherBound; j++) {
       doSomethingElse();
   }
   ```

I think the second one would be somewhat more readable, on the other hand I'd use j,k and so on to name inner loops... what do you think?

Comment: This isn't entirely language-agnostic, as one issue in C++ has been whether a variable declared in the scope of the `for` triplet should be considered out of scope after the end of the loop.

Comment: A side question: why i, j, k? Why not Loop1, Loop2, Loop3, or something a bit clearer? (I'm ok with i, j, k, but then I started programming back when you had at most 2 characters for a variable, and the integer variables *started* with "i".)

Comment: @Philip It's just that I'm used to it, of course you could take whichever you want :-).

Comment: @Steven Sry, you're right... changed that...

Comment: @Helper, absolutely, I'm just kind of surprised people still use i, j, k.

Comment: @Philip: The whole i, j, k thing dates back to Fortran, where variables had to be short, and the first letter controlled their data type. Now, it's just inertia.

Comment: @Steven Sudit - Why does it (in this case) matter whether the i in the first example is out of scope after the loop. He is assigning it a value of 0 at the start of the second loop anyhow.

Comment: @Steven Sudit 2nd comment - i,j,k ... are also most commonly used indexes in mathematics and non-programming sciences, so that probably helps with the choice as well.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: There is no issue in C++. The indices are definitely out of scope after the loop body in C++. There was a broken compiler from a certain company that caused problems for many years of course...

Comment: @ldigas: We may have a chicken and egg dilemma here. :-)

Comment: @Troubadour: It was different in K&R C, though, so it's still language-specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reuse the variable name in this case. The reason being that `i` is sort of international programmerese for "loop control variable whose name isn't really important". `j` is a bit less clear on that score, and once you have to start using `k` and beyond it gets kind of obscure.

One thing I should add is that when you use **nested** loops, you do have to go to `j`, `k`, and beyond. Of course if you have more than three nested loops, I'd highly suggest a bit of refactoring.

Comment: j is perfectly clear as well, imho, but it is more commonly used for the second index.

Answer (score 1):

first one is good for me,. cz that would allow you to use j, k in your inner loops., and because you are resetting i = 0 in the second loop so there wont be any issues with old value being used

Answer (score 1):

In a way you wrote your loops the counter is not supposed to be used outside the loop body. So there's nothing wrong about using the same variable names.

As for readability `i, j, k` are commonly used as variable names for counters. So it is even better to use them rather then pick the next letter over and over again.

Comment: I would have to disagree, because `j` is used only a loop nested inside an outer `i` loop, and so on. If I see a `j`, I expect nesting.

Answer (score 1):

I find it interesting that so many people have different opinions on this. Personally I prefer the first method, if for no other reason then to keep j and k open. I could see why people would prefer the second one for readability, but I think any coder worth handing a project over to is going to be able to see what you're doing with the first situation.

Answer (score 1):

The variable should be named something related to the operation or the boundary condition.

For example:
'indexOfPeople',
'activeConnections', or
'fileCount'.

If you are going to use 'i', 'j', and 'k', then reserve 'j' and 'k' for nested loops.

Comment: +1 - Variables should be named for what they mean. I wouldn't use i,j,k unless I was doing matrix multiplications or something like that.

Comment: @Jeff: Sometimes you don't want to emphasize the irrelevant index variable that's scoped to the loop. Calling it `index` would also work, but may be giving it more time on stage than it deserves.

Comment: @Steven Sudit - Maybe so. I often use `index` for the purpose. My habits started back in the VB3 days when I had to maintain somebody else's software that had a lot of single-letter variables. Just try to find all the uses of the variable `i` in a twenty-thousand line program using an early 1990's IDE. `Dim x as integer` gives two false-positives, and that's just one line. It was impossible to be confident of how a variable was used back then if it was only one letter.

Comment: @Jeff: If you use a regexp-supporting search, or have the option explicitly, you can have it find `i` only when it's a word in itself. Having said that, I'm not against using a longer name *if* it benefits the code. My concern is that the fact that it's an index is obvious regardless of its name, so fleshing it out doesn't add much value.

Comment: If the benefit of giving a descriptive name to an index is too low, it is probably a sign you should have used a collection and a foreach statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
void doSomethingInALoop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < someBound; i++) {
    doSomething();
  }
}

void doSomethingElseInALoop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < anotherBound; i++) {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the loops are doing the same things (the loop control -- not the loop body, i.e. they are looping over the same array or same range), then I'd use the same variable.

If they are doing different things -- A different array, or whatever, then I'd use use different variables.

Answer (score 0):

So, on the one-hundredth loop, you'd name the variable "zzz"?

The question is really irrelevant since the variable is defined local to the for-loop.  Some flavors of C, such as on OpenVMS, require using different names.  Otherwise, it amounts to programmer's preference, unless the compiler restricts it.

Comment: I agree 100%, except that if you have more than 24 of them in one scope, you **really** need to refactor your code.

Comment: Well, yeah: but the point is, who cares if you use the same one for each loop or use a different one for each loop? If it program compiles and meets the programming standards of the shop you're programming for, the question is completely irrelevant.

Comment: It's relevant to deciding what the programming standards *should* be, though.